# Splitting of totally geodesic Riemannian foliations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, holonomy

Let $\mathcal F$ be a non-singular Riemannian foliation on $(M,g)$ whose leaves are totally geodesic. Suppose further that the leaves are Riemannian products of irreducible manifolds $L=L_0\times ...\times L_s$. Keeping in mind that (local) holonomy transformations are isometries:

**Does, in some sense, the splitting $L=L_0\times...\times L_s$ induces a splitting of the foliation?**

(one can assume compact $M$ with closed leaves)

For instance, are there orthogonal Riemannian foliations $\mathcal F_i$, $i=0,...,s$ whose leaves are $L_i$? (at least locally)

Even an answer for Riemannian submersions could be enlightening.

Comment: Since there is one vote up, maybe it is worth to mention: it seems that the answer to the question in bold is yes. I proof should be put on arXiv soon.